# How i generate lotto number using ajax and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I want to generate the lotto number like generating here

http://www.nationallottery.co.za/lotto_home/NumberGenerator.asp

may i know what will be the logic or way to generate the lotto number using PHP,mysql and Ajax.

I will be thankful of you.

Comment: random number generator?

Answer (score 2):

Sample Example:

```
$generated = array();
    while (count($generated) < 6)
    {
        $no = mt_rand(1, 49);
        if(!array_search($no, $generated))
        {
             $generated[] = $no;
        }
    }

    echo implode(" : ", $generated);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to generate random numbers.

Create multiple random numbers and style them however you want them. That site appears to have replaced text numbers with images which are probably programatically coded. If you want multiple rows like they offer, just make a form like they have and return the correct number of rows. Shouldn't be too hard

Answer (score 0):

The php function you are looking for is [`mt_rand()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

Use it to generate an integer between two given values, something like this:

```
<?php
for($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++){
    echo mt_rand(1,45).' ';
    }
?>
```